# Keycloak impersonation only for certain users

Tags: keycloak

I am currently trying to set up keycloak for a production scenario in which I have different contexts, each with users and admins. The admin should only be able to impersonate users from his context.

Giving an admin permission in the form of permissions to impersonate all users is not a problem. but how can I solve the above task? Can one of keycloak built in concepts (groups, roles, realms, scopes etc.) help me?

Comment: it seems the mentioned admin isn't master admin. right ? if admin is only admin of some of users then it means they are many admins. from this scenario, you should write your own impersonation end-point and to control accesses use keycloak authorization feature.

Comment: yes thats the case

Comment: or intercept the impersonate end-point (admin) with the proxy or somethings else then just apply your authorization.

Comment: Impersonation using token endpoint or Keycloak admin UI? If it's the former, you can create a Keycloak policy to lock it down. More info here - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange

Comment: token endpoint, i know this documentation but cant figure out how to realize this policy. Im creating a policy for my admin user which defines that he is authorized to impersonate user, but i dont know how to restrict that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable --features=admin-fine-grained-authz  and then.

- Put your users into a group.
- Create another user and grant this user "query-groups" and
  "impersonation" roles (from the "realm-management" or "master-realm"
  client, depending on the realm).
- Go to your group, enable permissions, open "view" permission, and add a
  user policy to allow the user to view a group, then repeat for "view-members" permission.
  FInd more details [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/admin-console-permissions/fine-grain.adoc)
  and [here](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-July/014570.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to restrict both who can impersonate and who can be impersonated. To define who can be impersonated, you have to enable admin-fine-grained-authz and configure the Authorization in the realm-management client:

Clients > realm-management > Authorization > Permissions

Any policies referring to the "user-impersonated" scope define which users can be impersonated. This way you could add a group based policy for this scope, to allow only members of this group to be impersonated.

For further information: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#full-list-of-permissions